# Cannot hide a default text line from ag-grid-angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I use ag-grid-angular. For some reason it shows a line of "Drag here to set row groups" above columns by default. Is there an option to hide this line?

Answer (score 0):

removing the property "rowGroupPanelShow" removes this default line